# pick up sim call from application not working in android 4.4.2 (KitKat)

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, telephony, phone-call, telephonymanager

I need to pick the sim phone from my application. Its working fine in all devices, but its not working in Lg Lucid Vs876 which have a 4.4.2 kitkat version.

Here is my code for pick the phone from my application.

```
try {
                    if (AndroidVersionUtil.isApiVersionGraterOrEqual(21)) {
                        answerCall();
                        finish();
                    }else {
                        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
                        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT,new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP,KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK));
                        //i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT, new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK));
                        sendOrderedBroadcast(i,  null);
                        finish();
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

here is answer call method for greater than 21

```
public void answerCall() {
        try {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("input keyevent " +
                    Integer.toString(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK));

        } catch (IOException e) {
            answerRingingCallWithIntent();
        }
    }
```

I don't understand why its not working in 4.4.2.
is there any mistake i have done?
Any help?